# General solutions to differential equations and loss of information about eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

my question is related to solving differential equations with boundary conditions.  Lets, for example, say that you have a differential equation:

$$a\frac{\mathrm{d^4}y }{\mathrm{d} x^4} + b\frac{\mathrm{d^2} y}{\mathrm{d} x^2} + cy=0$$

Where a, b, and c are some constants.  You of course assume an exponential solution and let's say you end up with the characteristic equation given by:

$$a\lambda^4 + b\lambda^2 + c = 0$$

With eigenvalues given by:

$$\lambda = \alpha \pm \beta i,   \lambda = -\alpha \pm \beta i$$

Then, the general solution would be:

$$y(x) = A_{1} e^{\lambda_{1}x} + A_{2} e^{\lambda_{2}x} + A_{3} e^{\lambda_{3}x} + A_{4} e^{\lambda_{4}x}$$

Now, I understand how to switch between the trig functions and hyperbolic trig functions, however, I have read some journal articles that have expressed the above equation in 3 different ways:

(1)  $$y(x) = B_{1} \cosh(\alpha x) \cos(\beta x) + B_{2} \sinh(\alpha x) \cos(\beta x) + B_{3} \sinh(\alpha x) \sin(\beta x) + B_{4} \cosh(\alpha x) \sin(\beta x)$$

(2)  $$y(x) = C_{1} \cos(\lambda x) + C_{2}\cos(\lambda x) + C_{3} \sin(\lambda x) + C_{4}\sin(\lambda x)$$

(3) $$ y(x) = C_{1} \cosh(\lambda x) + C_{2}\cosh(\lambda x) + C_{3} \sinh(\lambda x) + C_{4}\sinh(\lambda x)$$

Then, they go onto substitute the above into the boundary conditions to find the transcendental equation for the eigenvalues.  However, my question is, the author that used the (1) way of solving the problem made it seem like it had to be done that way and it made me wonder if there was information lost about the eigenvalues when using the (2) or (3) solution to the (1) method.  Do they all essentially end at the same result?  Or, is it incorrect to do it the (2) and (3) way?